# Multiple Jtextfields to one Jbutton

Tags: jbutton, jtextfield

I am wondering how to put 4 separate Jtextfields into one Jbutton where if you enter 3 values into the textfields and press the button, they will display the new value in the 4th textfield.

```
btnDoIt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double a;
        a = Double.parseDouble(txtA.getText());
        txtOutput.setText("The root(s) of the equation is(are): " + a);
        double b;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add condition checking, and remember to make your question clear. The following code may help you

```
btnDoIt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //get text from first 3 textfields
        String s1 = txtA.getText();
        String s2 = txtB.getText();
        String s3 = txtC.getText();
        //make sure strings aren't empty
        if(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty() || s3.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        //set text of final textfield
        txtOutput.setText(/*Your operation here*/);
    }
});
```